# Ionic Menu is disabled after navigation - v4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I've two pages (A and B) that each has it own ionic menu. 
The menu is displayed using the ion-menu-button in both pages.
If I return from the page B to A, the menu does not show on page A. If I don't go to page B, the menu on page A works.
In this scenario, the menu on page A is missing the class "menu-enabled".

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MenuController for this.

```
import { MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';

constructor(public menu: MenuController) {

}

ionViewWillEnter() {
   //If you want the menu to be enabled when you enter a page
   this.menu.enable(true);
}

ionViewDidLeave() {
   // disable it when leaving the page
   this.menu.enable(false);
}
```

You can use the opposite of this if you wish to also depending on how you wish the menu to be present on your page